# How to call a Powershell commandlet from vb.net to set -ObjectAttributes

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory

I am performing a basic 'new-QADUser' task and need to setup a number of -ObjectAttributes, ie: userprinciplename, employeeid, extensionAttribute2, etc.  I am currently using a Command object and setting Parameter key/value pairs.

```
 .....
 Dim myCommand As New Command("new-QADUser")
 myCommand.Parameters.Add("Name", "BSmith")
 myCommand.Parameters.Add("SamAccountName", "BSmith")
 myCommand.Parameters.Add("userprinciplename", ?????)
```

Optionally, I could setup a PSCommand and run this as a more conventional Powershell string - ie:

```
Dim myCommand as New String = "new-QADUser -name " + myName + "-ObjectAttributes @{userprinciplename=" + myUserPrinclipleName.....
```

But I would rather stay with the former approach.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  I'm not sure what the problem is.  Have you tried different types of values for those parameters?

Comment: You're wrapping a (deprecated) powershell cmdlet inside a vbscript?!?!? Why not just run the command directly?

Comment: No error, I'm not able to add parameters to set values like "userprinciplename" which are ObjectAttributes (ie: "-ObjectAttributes @{userprinciplename=" + myUserPrinclipleName).  "new-QADUser" still shows to be a current part of the Quest powershell tools.  I have a VB.Net application handling all of the data and need to call this Powershell cmdlet to handle this one piece.  For each new user account, I need to perform 20 tasks, only one being against AD.